# Custom Jackson deserializer not able to determine target class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I currently have a Join object that I am trying to write a custom deserializer for.  We store the database key and the Java class name of the object in the JSON, and that looks something like this:

```
{
    "@class": "com.mysite.data.ExpertFor",
    "id": "expert-for-1",
    "leftId": "user-profile-1",
    "leftType": "com.mysite.data.UserProfile",
    "rightId": "hotel-1",
    "rightType": "com.mysite.data.Hotel"
}
```

We do this so we don't have to store the actual object in the database; rather, we retrieve it when we deserialize it.  The issue is that my custom serializer cannot see the `@class` element in the JSON stream - therefore, it cannot properly instantiate the needed object after all the data is read.  Here is my deserializer:

```
public Join deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    // Loop through the JSON document and pull out all
    // the values and put them into the map
    JsonToken token = jp.nextToken();
    while (token != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        logger.info("Non-data field: [" + token + "], name is [" + jp.getCurrentName() + "], text is [" + jp.getText() + "]");
        if (token == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            values.put(jp.getCurrentName(), jp.getText());
        }
        token = jp.nextToken();
    }         
    // remainder of code omitted for brevity
}
```

Now, the Log4J lines that are written to the logs show all of the appropriate elements of the JSON I would expect, EXCEPT the `@class` element

```
Data field: [VALUE_STRING], name is [id], text is [expert-for-1]
Data field: [VALUE_STRING], name is [leftId], text is [user-profile-1]
Data field: [VALUE_STRING], name is [rightId], text is [hotel-1]
Data field: [VALUE_STRING], name is [leftType], text is [com.mysite.data.UserProfile]
Data field: [VALUE_STRING], name is [rightType], text is [com.mysite.data.Hotel]
```

I have tried adding the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation to my class, like

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
```

but it appears the element is getting 'swallowed' by the code, and I don't know how to get at it.  And I need this, because any descendants of `Join` will need to be deserialized.  Here is some additional information about the hierarchy this class is in:

Adding the @TypeInfo annotation was only there as an attempt to try and see what was going on.  I am getting the same behavior whether that is there or not.  What's really strange is that we are using this same basic functionality in other classes that need custom deserialization and those see the @class just fine.  Here is the heirarchy of this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(value = JsonMethod.NONE)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public abstract class TaggedObject implements Serializable {
...
}
```

and then we have DataObject

```
public abstract class DataObject extends TaggedObject {
...
}
```

and then we have our Join class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = Join.Serializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = Join.Deserializer.class)
public abstract class Join<L, R> extends DataObject {
...
}
```

I would think the @JsonTypeInfo would be inherited from TaggedObject, but it is not seen here, whereas it is seen by other classes within the same hierarchy.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can grab the class of this object so I can create the appropriate object?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to manually handle @class AND declare it to be handled by Jackson with @JsonTypeInfo -- either let Jackson fully handle it (which it can and will do), or remove anntoation and handle things manually.

Answer (score 0):

using Jackson Tree Model, the following code prints the missing `@class`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
Iterator<String> iterator = root.fieldNames();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String fieldName = iterator.next();
    String fieldValue = root.get(fieldName).asText();
    System.out.println("name is [" + fieldName + "], text is [" + fieldValue + "]");
}
```

Output:

```
name is [@class], text is [com.mysite.data.ExpertFor]
name is [id], text is [expert-for-1]
name is [leftId], text is [user-profile-1]
name is [leftType], text is [com.mysite.data.UserProfile]
name is [rightId], text is [hotel-1]
name is [rightType], text is [com.mysite.data.Hotel]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.